# Place tags in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to place a "FULL" tag beside the event shown in the screenshot above.
I have researched about tags but all of that are input tags.

[Here's the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lby2Q.png)

Comment: Have you attempted anything? If your looking for suggestions or for us to write the code for you then that is not what SO is for. But if your having trouble coding something we would be happy to help.

Comment: Hello, you need to use https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_badges_labels.asp this for tags.